# How to put :hover css in jquery and change image source

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have css with :hover.

i want to change the current img source by some condition using jquery but i dont know how to add the hover.

```
#ctrl_mm_e_0_0:hover{
    background-image: url("../images/dashboard_hover.png");
    background-size:55px 55px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:70px;
    padding-left:280px;
    padding-top:50px;
    line-height: 0;
    width:70px; 
    font-size: 0;
    color: transparent;
    /*background-color:red; */    
}
```

this is my jquery to change current image to other image that i use but i dont know how to include the hover :

```
var htmlElement = $('html').attr('lang');

if (htmlElement == 'ms'){
$(ctrl_mm_e_0_0).css({"background-image":"url(../Customizing/global/skin/images/dashboard_grey.png"});
}
```

i use this code if the system change language. the html tag is change :

```
<html lang="ms" dir="ltr"></html> -- other language
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"></html> -- main language
```

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: sorry should be javascript. thanks

Comment: so you want to change the image by hovering on the image?

Comment: yes only by hover change the hover image url.. i try using $(ctrl_mm_e_0_0:hover) but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need JS for this issue. All you need is to extend your CSS:

```css
#ctrl_mm_e_0_0 {background-image: url(dashboard.png)}
#ctrl_mm_e_0_0:hover {background-image: url("dashboard_hover.png")}

html[lang="ms"] #ctrl_mm_e_0_0 {background-image: url("dashboard_ms.png")}
html[lang="ms"] #ctrl_mm_e_0_0:hover {background-image: url("dashboard_ms_hover.png")}
```

Comment: @airi, sorry cannot understand your comment.

Comment: can i use this html[lang="ms"] inside <style></style> ?

Comment: @airi, happy to help!